# Fetch all duplicate rows

Tags: sql

I want to fetch only duplicate rows with  repetition of values in **name** column occurring multiple times without the count column and I don't want to group them. Examples given below.
e.g.

for example this is table:-

```
    id |  name  | project 
----+--------+---------
  1 | aditya | java
  2 | aditya | cloud
  3 | bradly | go
  4 | cooper | java
  5 | alexa  | elixir 
  6 | jason  | search
  7 | jason  | java
```

result should be :-

```
   id |  name  | project 
----+--------+---------
  1 | aditya | java
  2 | aditya | cloud
  6 | jason  | search
  7 | jason  | java
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 3):

A simple method is to use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.name = t.name and t2.id <> t.id)
order by name;
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by name) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1
order by name;
```

Comment: Seconded - EXISTS is one of the most useful things I've discovered for filtering on join conditions and is incredibly efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could also either use a `join` or an `in`

```
select a.*
from t a
inner join t b on a.name=b.name and a.id<>b.id
```

**OR**

```
select *
from t
where name in (select name from t group by name having count(*)>1);
```